# A native way to automate clicking a windows form button? (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple batch file that automates a task we do frequently. (End all internet explorer processes, open Control Panel>Internet Settings>Advanced>Reset IE). This is the code

```meh-whatever-doesnt-matter-anyway
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults
```

The problem is that this Windows function throws up a final approval window:
[image]

Is there a native way in the batch file to simulate pressing the Reset button, or bypassing this and just executing it? *No third party software download.

Comment: To answer question. No. But if you used Vbscript you could accomplish your task.

Comment: that question referred to executing a button press in a non-Windows application. i didn't see it as related because Windows can talk to Windows better than it can talk to Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SendKeys()` from Windows Script Host to simulate keyboard navigation.  Generically, you could send <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus to different window controls, or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle a check box or activate a button.  Or if the controls you want to activate are already assigned hotkeys (usually labeled with one letter underlined), just send <kbd>Alt</kbd> + whatever letter is underlined.  In the case of this Internet Explorer dialog you're opening, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will toggle the check box, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will activate the Reset button.  See [Microsoft's SendKeys() documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx) for more details.

Here's a Batch + JScript hybrid example:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal
2>NUL taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
start "" rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults

cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0"
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code
var sh = WSH.CreateObject('Wscript.Shell');

sh.AppActivate("Reset Internet Explorer Settings");
sh.SendKeys("%p%r");
```

Here's another example, this time calling PowerShell from a .bat script:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
2>NUL taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
start "" rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults

powershell "$sh=new-object -COM Wscript.Shell;$sh.AppActivate('Reset Internet Explorer Settings');$sh.SendKeys('%p%r')"
```

Of course if there's a chance your scripts will be running on a Windows installation in a different language, you'd probably need to focus the reset window by its HWND rather than its title.  That's a subject for another lesson, though.